# Different look in desktop, how to setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to coding. I have made a page for mobile only but when it opens on laptop or pc the image takes the whole area. I want the image to be of the exact size of its pixels if the page opens on laptop or computer.

Here's the code:

```html
<div class="container" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="clickToShow();">
  <img src="images/mypicoo.jpg" alt="Norway" style="width:100%; height: auto;">
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `width:100%` from the style and put that in a media query for small screens.

Comment: Remove `width: 100%;` and set `max-width: 100%` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use media queries. On screens smaller than 600px width the image will be width 100%. On screens larger than 600px width the image width is auto meaning the size of the image. You might want to tweak that 600px for your project.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  img {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="clickToShow();">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/14/05/17/crow-3604685_960_720.jpg" alt="Norway">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to just add `max-width` instead of `width` like below

```css
.container {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 10px;
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="clickToShow();">
    <img src="https://mypicot.com/img/pt-2620.jpg" alt="Norway" style="max-width:100%; height:auto">
</div>
```